# Flutter The method 'openDrawer' was called on null. Navigator.pop(context) or on back widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

When I try to open the drawer in my flutter app I call `key.currentState.openDrawer();`
However, when i do a `navigator.pop(context)` or hit the back button and then call `key.currentState.openDrawer();` I get
the error `The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.`

Please help

Here is a link to a repo I made to demonstrate this bug. super easy to run and get started: https://github.com/brianschardt/flutter_drawer_bug

Base Widget I include in all my screens

```
class Base extends StatelessWidget {
  Base({this.child});
  final Widget child;

  final NavDrawerService navDrawerService = getIt<NavDrawerService>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    navDrawerService.key = new GlobalKey();//create a new key for every new page, save it in singleton service to open drawer from anywhere in the app.
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
      key: navDrawerService.key,
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, post some code showing your implementation.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele just added